# User Permissions - SharePoint 2013 Central Administration page and Sub-Site page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have installed SharePoint 2013 Foundation in a 2 server farm topography. I am trying to create a sub-site for normal authenticated users and keep the Central Administration root site for only the SP admins. When I create a sub-site I think I am adding a user group and users to that site, for access to only that site, but users in that group can still see the Central Administration site. I need to assign separate permissions on each site. Is there a tutorial or something out there that can help a beginner do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sort out Central Administration permission**

Go to your user permissions in Central Administration site, should be something like

```
      http://sharepointsite.domain:12345/_layouts/15/user.aspx
```

Make sure that only you Farm admin groups are listed here. I manually add only the Farm admin accounts to make sure nobody who should not be there find there way in.
If you have a Farm Administrators account, expand it and see what other groups might have permission.

You might find something like "BUILTIN\Administrators".. and there might be a global user group that is included in that account.

A good start is to delete all the accounts you are unsure about, then re-add them while checking each one.

And of course you can use the magic button that will show you permissions get granted to the site.

[image: Check Permissions in SharePoint 2013]

Comment: Thank you for the help. I deleted all the group except for Farm Admins and started over. It worked fine when I started from scratch.